# Extract HTML Tables from Multiple webpages Using R

Tags: html, r, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Hi I have done thorough research and have come to this extent. All I am trying to do is extract HTML table spanning many webpages.

I have to query the website sec.gov's database and the table then returns appropriate number of results (the size and number of pages vary with every query). For example:

Link: http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/srch-edgar

Inputs to be given:

**Enter a Search string box:** form-type=(8-k) AND filing-date=20140523

**Start:** 2014

**End:** 2014

How can I do this totally in R without even opening the browser?

I am sharing what all I have done

I tried many packages and the closest I came to was package RCurl. But in getURL function I opened the browser, ran the query in browser and pasted it in getURL. It returned a very long character, which has the URLs that can be looped and produce the output I want. All this information is in the "center" tag of output.

Now I do not know how to get those URLs out from the middle of the character.

Also, this is not what I wanted. I wanted to run a web query directly from R and get the varied HTML table outputs directly into R. is this possible at all?

Thanks
Meena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You will want to use a combination of the RCurl and XML packages. You will need to programmatically generate the query parameters in the URL (based on the HTML form) and then use `getURL()` or `getURLContent()`. Sometimes, the server will expect an HTTP POST, so there is `postForm()`.

To parse the result, look up the XPath language, which the XML package supports with `getNodeSet()`. I think there is also a function in the XML package for parsing an HTML table into a `data.frame`.

You might want to invest in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461478995).

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will buy the book, but I do not usually deal with XML. How can I gain comprehensive overview of R functions?